# How its differentiate this function?

Tags: derivatives, newton-raphson

I'm trying to use the Newton-Raphson in this function:

$$f(t)=0.5-e^{-\sqrt{2}t} \left(\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt2}t+\sin\frac{2}{\sqrt2}t \right) $$

I calculate the derivative with the product rule applying the product of the exponential with each trigonometric function, it yields

$$f(\dot{t})=\sqrt{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}t}\left(\cos \frac{2t}{\sqrt{2}}+ \sin \frac{2t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{2e^{-\sqrt{2}t}}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt2}t-\sin\frac{2}{\sqrt2}t\right)$$

In the classroom it was said that the right answer is
$$f\left(\dot{t}\right)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\sqrt{2}t}\sin\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}t$$

but this was not explained why.

Which one is the right derivate? Or both are not good?

Comment: I think you mean to say $f'(t)$ rather than $t'$ which means the derivative of $t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error of sign:

$$\dot f=\sqrt{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}t}(\cos \frac{2t}{\sqrt{2}}+ \sin \frac{2t}{\sqrt{2}})\color{red}-\frac{2e^{-\sqrt{2}t}}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos\frac{2}{\sqrt2}t-\sin\frac{2}{\sqrt2}t)$$

than, with  a bit of algebra, you can see that the result is the same as the classroom answer.